# Android: Place 4 buttons on RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place 4 buttons to fill all the relative layout.. I want each button have width and height till the center of the RelativeLayout (with about 2dp space between them).. I don't think that I can explain it very good, so I have made an image and here is the code I have made... 
Any ideas?? 
Thank you!!
[image] The view right now is: [image]

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have even tried? what have you done so far? whats the look of your layout now? If you want that kind of layouting, I suggest Linearlayout.

Comment: I have tried with layout_weight but I could find any solution with 4 buttons... Let me try Linear Layout..

Comment: This should be fairly easy with the tools provided by Android Studio.  Give me like 10 minutes.  I'll post an answer.  Unless 2 people beat me to the punch...  Haha...  Nevermind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I used two linear layouts instead of one relative layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works!!!! (I approve the other answer only to take a little more reputation, but thank you very much!!! :) )